# Can Google Cloud SQL perform automatic instance failover across zones?

Tags: mysql, high-availability, google-cloud-sql

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/introduction?_ga=1.10456821.1926559505.1400087079#features), data of Cloud SQL is replicated across multiple zones. But this can only prevent data loss in the event of zone outage. In order to ensure high availability of the service, does Cloud SQL offer cross-zone DB instance failover capability similar to [Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Cloud SQL data is replicated in multiple zones. If there is a zone outage then the instance fails over to another, available, zone automatically.

See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#replication

Comment: The docs you referenced is still about data replication, not about instance auto-failover. Is there any official documentation explaining failover? For example, Amazon RDS states failover is performed along with with DNS flip.

Comment: The failover is designed to be transparent to the application: same instance name, same IP address, same firewall rules. The only visible affects should be:
1. a few seconds downtime as the new instance starts up
2. existing connections will be broken
3. the cache will be empty

Comment: Thanks Joe. I'm an architect of a large org seeking a solution to make a WordPress app technically justified highly available - one that eliminates all single point of failures up to metro area/data ctr level. Comparing to on-premise installation, for a cloud-based alternative, I understand ultimately  I have to take words from the provider . Since you are Google Cloud product manager, could you please facilitate adding the auto-failover description to the official documentation, so that at least I can take words from an official source?

Comment: Also, I wonder what technology do you use to failover on a single IP. Is it BGP IP anycast? If so, can network convergence completed in just a few sec? If not, I assume it is achieved by some kind of intelligent "switch". Then doesn't the switch itself become a single point of failure? Thanks

Comment: Noticed a section *How does Google Cloud SQL failover work?* is added below the replication.

Comment: "The only visible affects should be: 1. a few seconds downtime" is highly inaccurate in my experience.  A few minutes downtime is a more reasonable claim.  Heck Google don't even instigate the failover process until your primary has been unresponsive for 60 seconds.  Then the failover instance has to startup, run the redo log, then restart again. Google docs claim 2-3 minutes for a failover, but i would treat this as a minimum.  It's easy to do your own testing to quantify this for your database setup.

Answer (score 1):

Failover is automatic and mostly transparent to the client, all database clients need to do is reconnect when the connection is lost
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability

This is not what many 'Enterprise' databases would consider high availability, Products such as Oracle RAC with hot/hot or master/master setups would failover transparently and clients would not notice that an instance had died, the application would keep on running without any outage.

With CloudSQL your failover instance is cold and gets started up after Google has noticed your primary instance has stopped responding for an minute.  So there is still an outage for a few minutes.  The main advantage is the replication, if a disaster takes out the whole zone you can be up and running on another zone in a few minutes.